# How do you convert a hexadecimal of type string to number in JS?

Tags: javascript, hex, byte

Let's say I have a hexadecimal, for example `"0xdc"`, how do I convert this hexadecimal `string` to a hexadecimal `Number` type in JS?

Literally just losing the quotes. The `Number()` constructor and `parseInt()` just converted it to an integer between 0 and 255, I just want `0xdc`.

EDIT:

To make my point more clear: 
I want to go from `"0xdc"` (of type `String`), to `0xdc` (of type `Number`)

Comment: This question is "wrong" as two different things are conflated: one is the value and the other is the representation.  The computer stores the value in binary as `11011100` - you can check that by running `parseInt("0xDC", 16).toString(2)`.  Representing it in Hex or Decimal or any Base is just a representation thing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the `Number` function, which parses a string into a number according to a certain format.

```js
console.log(Number("0xdc"));
```

JavaScript uses some notation to recognize numbers format like -

1. `0x` = Hexadecimal
2. `0b` = Binary
3. `0o`  = Octal

Comment: Nope, that stills returns an exact number, 220. I want the literal byte, so instead of `"0xdc"`, I want `0xdc`

Comment: What do you want to do with `0xdc` `Number` type?. As if you assign any variable like `var v = 0xdc` and if you try to do `console.log(v)` it will give 220 not `0xdc`

Comment: I want to send it to be dynamic value in a Buffer that I send over UDP, for instance:

`Buffer.from([0x00, 0x0E, dynamicStringValue, 0xef])`

`dynamicStringValue` should be a number instead of a string for my buffer to work correctly, right?

Comment: Seeing the answer above, you were right. I can just send the integer that results from your code to my buffer. Thanks.

Comment: The `parseInt()` here is redundant. `Number()` already returns a number type (which internally is just stored in 1's and 0's and doesn't have a notion of whether the original string was binary/octal/decimal/hexadecimal). All `parseInt()` does here, is turn the result of `Number("0xdc")` back into a (decimal/base-10) string, and then turns it into the same number again.

Answer (score 8):

if you want convert string to hex representation, you can covert to number with 16 as  radix.

```
parseInt("0xdc", 16)  // gives you 0xdc
```

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR

@dhaker 's answer of

`parseInt(Number("0xdc"), 10)` is correct.

### In-Memory Number Representation

Both numbers  `0xdc` and `220` are represented in the same way in javascript

so
`0xdc == 220` will return true.
the prefix `0x` is used to tell javascript that the number is `hex`

**So wherever you are passing `220` you can safely pass `0xdc` or vice-versa**

### String Format

Numbers are always shown in base 10 unless specified not to.

`'0x' + Number(220).toString(16)` gives `'0xdc'` if you want to print it as string.

---

In a nutshell

`parseInt('0x' + Number(220).toString(16),16) => 220`

Comment: Ahh I see, I understood wrong. I can just use the base 10 representation. Thanks.

Comment: Why call both `parseInt()` and `Number()`? Only calling `Number()` is sufficient like this: `Number("0xdc")`