# How to convert from "unicode number" to utf16-be with javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have a table of unicode numbers like `U+1f618` which represents smiles. This one is mapped to a smile "Face Throwing a kiss". According to [this doc](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F618/) it has utf-16-be hex code `D8 3D DE 18`, which is `\ud83d\ude18` in browser.

- What is a "Unicode number"?
- How to get `D8 3D DE 18` from `U+1f618` using javascript?

Comment: The numbers `d83d de18` are Unicode **code units**, and `U+1f618` is Unicode **code point**. When you look Javascript documentation you should check carefully which one they use (it depends on the API: old is *code unit* based, so compatible with old Unicode where 16bit was *enough*. New functions uses codepoints. *Surrogates* is also a word used to describe how to transform one into the other: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogateshttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to mess with internal details of the UTF-16 encoding, just tell Javascript you want that codepoint:

```js
str = String.fromCodePoint(0x1f618)
console.log(str)
```

If what you've got is a hex string like `1F618`, you get to convert it to a number first:

```js
str = String.fromCodePoint(parseInt('1F618', 16))
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert a string `1F618` to `String.fromCodePoint` argument? I have  a lib that contains string representation of codePoint. I can think only of js `eval` method

Comment: @deathangel908: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009465/how-do-you-convert-a-hexadecimal-of-type-string-to-number-in-js

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi How do I pass `Number('0x1f618')` to `String.fromCharCode` ? It doesn't return correct info

Comment: I used `eval(\`String.fromCodePoint('0x${a}')\`)`

Comment: @deathangel908: no need for eval, see update